# Woocommerce Ajax add to cart programmatically

Tags: ajax, wordpress, woocommerce

I have this button:

```
<a href="http://my-site/checkout/" target="_blank" class="dt-sc-button">bla bla</a>
```

This button is located on my homebage and is generated by a page builder. What I want to accomplish is when somebody click on the button, it will take them on the checkout, and add a product to the cart. I know that this can be accomplished via a URL, but I need to have this button do other things as well(client idea).

So right now I'm stucked here:

JQuery

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){     
$(".remove-all").click(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: "wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
        data: 'myajax'
    });
  });
});
```

PHP

```
add_action('wp_ajax_myajax', 'myajax');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_myajax', 'myajax');

    function myajax() {
        global $woocommerce;
        $product_id = 264;
    $woocommerce->cart->add_to_cart($product_id);
    die();
    }
```

I'm a javascript noob, so can you please point me to the right direction,  or maybe give me a hint on what I'm doing wrong.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is happening currently? Are you receiving some kind of error?

Comment: No, I don't. When I checked the console, no warnings or errors, the only thing i noticed: after clicking the button, it loads the link which goes to : example.com/checkout, than it goes straight to the cart without adding a product. Makes sense?

Comment: Friendly reminder that clients can come up with some dumb stuff. As pros, it is our job to guide them. :) That said, `$(".remove-all")` as a selector doesn't match the class on your `<a>` element so nothing is ever going to happen. Also, WooCommerce *has* a ajax add to cart functionality, see [here](https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/blob/master/includes/class-wc-ajax.php#L396) and [here](https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/blob/master/assets/js/frontend/add-to-cart.js#L10). There's no need to re-invent the wheel.

Comment: Oh and PS- if JS is disabled, the link will just take someone to the checkout without actually adding anything to the cart.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comments, you can pretty much borrow from core WooCommerce functions.

First, here's the button we'll be trying to ajaxify:

```
<a href="http://local.wordpress.dev/checkout/" class="button test-button">bla bla</a>
```

Secondly, we'll load our custom script and pass it important variables such as the admin ajax and checkout urls.

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'so_load_script', 20 );
function so_load_script(){
    wp_enqueue_script( 'so_test', plugins_url( 'js/test.js', __FILE__ ) );
    $i18n = array( 'ajax_url' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ), 'checkout_url' => get_permalink( wc_get_page_id( 'checkout' ) ) );
    wp_localize_script( 'so_test', 'SO_TEST_AJAX', $i18n );
}
```

Now we will write our ajax callbacks, which is copied almost verbatim from WooCommerce core with only a few small modifications:

```
add_action('wp_ajax_myajax', 'myajax_callback');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_myajax', 'myajax_callback');

    /**
     * AJAX add to cart.
     */
function myajax_callback() {        
        ob_start();

        //$product_id        = 264;
        $product_id        = 34;
        $quantity          = 1;
        $passed_validation = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation', true, $product_id, $quantity );
        $product_status    = get_post_status( $product_id );

        if ( $passed_validation && WC()->cart->add_to_cart( $product_id, $quantity ) && 'publish' === $product_status ) {

            do_action( 'woocommerce_ajax_added_to_cart', $product_id );

            wc_add_to_cart_message( $product_id );

        } else {

            // If there was an error adding to the cart, redirect to the product page to show any errors
            $data = array(
                'error'       => true,
                'product_url' => apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_redirect_after_error', get_permalink( $product_id ), $product_id )
            );

            wp_send_json( $data );

        }

        die();

}
```

And finally the contents of `test.js`:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){     
  $(".test-button").click(function(e){ 
    e.preventDefault();  // Prevent the click from going to the link

    $.ajax({
        url: wc_add_to_cart_params.ajax_url,
        method: 'post',
        data: { 
            'action': 'myajax'
        }
    }).done( function (response) {
          if( response.error != 'undefined' && response.error ){
            //some kind of error processing or just redirect to link
            // might be a good idea to link to the single product page in case JS is disabled
            return true;
          } else {
            window.location.href = SO_TEST_AJAX.checkout_url;
          }
    });

  });

});
```

Comment: will this refresh the page? or "Add to cart" will happen via ajax . @helgatheviking

Comment: At @mehmoodkhan I have no idea if 5 year old code is going to work but `window.location.href = SO_TEST_AJAX.checkout_url;` suggests my effort was to try to redirect to the checkout if the add to cart part was successful.

Answer (score 1):

You likely need to cancel/prevent the default action of clicking the link, and then redirect once the AJAX call finishes (this is just one way to do it):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){     
  $(".remove-all").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();  // Prevent the click from going to the link
    var $redirect = $(this).attr('href');        

    $.ajax({
        url: "wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
        data: 'myajax',
        success: function () {
          window.location.href = $redirect;
        }
    });
  });
});
```

PHP

```
add_action('wp_ajax_myajax', 'myajax');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_myajax', 'myajax');

function myajax() {
    $product_id = 264;
    // Avoid using the global $woocommerce object
    WC()->cart->add_to_cart($product_id);
    die();
}
```

Comment: I still get the same behaviour. It does prevent the default action of the button, but I still get no product added to the cart

Comment: Are you sure that your AJAX URL is correctly pointing to `admin-ajax.php`?

Comment: I think so. To be honest, I don't know how to check if AJAX URL is correctly pointing to `admin-ajax.php`, but I have a variable in my theme `ajaxurl:'example.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php` , and I replaced `wp-admin/admin-ajax.php` with `ajaxurl` and I see no changes.

Comment: Normally, it is best to pass the `ajaxurl` in via `wp_localize_script()`, but WooCommerce already does that so you can access it via `wc_add_to_cart_params.ajax_url` as long as you enqueue your custom script after WooCommerce loads its `add-to-cart.js` script.

Comment: PS- @rnevius careful, there's no validation in your callback.