# Adding item to woocommerce cart

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce

While writing a plug-in, I'm trying to add items to a WooCommerce cart in Ajax.

I've added the following lines in my main my-plugin.php

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_add_items_to_cart', 'ajax_add_items_to_cart' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_add_items_to_cart', 'ajax_add_items_to_cart' );
function ajax_add_items_to_cart() {
  global $woocommerce;
  $product_id  = absint( $_POST['product_id'] );
  $quantity = absint( $_POST['quantity'] );
  $variation = 0;
  $cart_item_data['key'] = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['key'] );
  $cart_item_data['other_data'] = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['other_data'] );
  $cart_item_key = $woocommerce->cart->add_to_cart($product_id, $quantity,  $variation, $cart_item_data);
  wp_die();
}
```

but the cart remains empty. Any hints?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Woocommerce Ajax add to cart programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33656739/woocommerce-ajax-add-to-cart-programmatically)

Comment: You have just forgotten the Javascript/jQuery code, as Ajax works with Javascript… See the link above (and many other threads).

Comment: In fact, I've omitted it as my test show I'm entered the function properly with the rights arguments. In fact, every thing seems to work fine with no error message except that no product lands in the cart.

Answer (score 1):

OK, in fact, no issue with this code, my problem was somewhere else in the code and I was sending an unknown product_id to WooCommerce.